# Using LEFT on a TEXT-field in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

In a table, I have a text-field. I need to be able to select only the first 200 chars of the field - but LEFT does not work with TEXT-fields.

What to do?

Comment: Are you sure you want the *first 200 chars* and not the *sentences contained in the first 200 chars*?

Comment: That would be even better - but that is another question. :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

instead of left . try with [SUBSTRING](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187748.aspx)

e.g : `select SUBSTRING(TEXT,1,200)  from dbo.tblText`

Comment: interesting! I didn't think SUBSTRING would work on a TEXT column - but it does indeed! I'm amazed.......

Comment: Awesome! Strange that substring works, but not left. I would think LEFT implemented Subtext to do the grunt work.

Answer (score 5):

You cannot apply string manipulation functions on TEXT fields - you should stop using TEXT anyway, since it will be removed from SQL Server soon!

What you can do is convert your TEXT column to VARCHAR(MAX) And then use the string gfunction:

```
SELECT LEFT(CAST(YourTextCol AS VARCHAR(MAX), 200) .....
```